# Shell script using variable to store output redirection

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, redirection

I have a 'simple' script which runs a few commands, I normally just want to see a few echo's letting me know where it is up to. But occasionally I need a verbose output which shows me the output of some of the commands being executed.

Example for normal use

```
echo "Simple message"
wget 'http://example.com' > /dev/null
```

Verbose option

```
echo "Simple message"
wget 'http://example.com'
```

I thought of using a variable to store the output redirection

```
output=""
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    output="> /dev/null"
fi
echo "Simple message"
wget 'http://example.com' $output
```

Problem is it didn't seem to be working, so I added -x to the shebang and the output shows me

```
wget 'http://example.com' '>' /dev/null
```

How can I stop the `>` from being single quoted?

There's more going on in the original script than a simple wget, this is just a short example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting wget to stdout allows you to change your script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="/dev/stdout"
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
output="/dev/null"
fi
echo "simple message"
wget -qO- 'http://example.com' > "$output"
```

This way, whenever your first parameter is empty it will always redirect to /dev/null, otherwise output to stdout.

If you didn't want it to output to stdout, I'd suggest creating a file (which will always be the same) and then reading from it after the wget.

Comment: when $output is empty, then this command would be

   wget 'http://www.example.com' > ""

How does redirection work here, does it just assume stdout?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain all of that. I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you @robbie, that looks great, will test it out later.